# Skip showing external command to be run when invoking `:grep`

Tags: vim

Let's say I have many files:

```
for i in $(seq 1 1000)
do
  if [ $((1 + RANDOM % 100)) -lt 2 ]
  then
    echo "needle" > $(uuid)
  else
    echo "haystack" > $(uuid)
  fi
done
```

which I then edit with `vim`:

```
find . -type f | xargs -o vi --clean
```

I can search in these files via:

```
:vimgrep needle ##
```

or:

```
:grep needle ##
```

However, when I use the latter, `vim` does two things that I would like it to skip:

- shows me the external command that it will execute, in this case pages of:

```
:!grep -n needle ./499553b6-615d-11ed-9ef7-5f9f4b37d6da ./484c2354-615d-11ed-94ff-a3a9a2d52531 ./49492e82-615d-11ed-af5d-5363f17c2e2b ./4ab7cc42-615d-11ed-8d84-4fd2cdf1942
c ./4ad4a132-615d-11ed-8af6-2f5cbf24f5de ./4c1f26c0-615d-11ed-b630-6bcbd445b4a1 ./4de4b948-615d-11ed-8e82-4f0c16b0065e <snip>
```

- asks me to `Press ENTER or type command to continue` before starting to edit the matching files

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't depend on specific features of your `:help 'grepprg'`, then `:help :vimgrep` is your best choice because the work is done internally.

If you do, then you will have to use a different command because `:help :grep` shells out and it can't really be made to work silently. You might find mappings online that press the dreaded `<CR>` for you but they don't really fix anything.

The `:help :cexpr` family of commands is a less noisy alternative that allows you to use `:help system()` and thus remove both the shelling-out and the `<CR>` problem:

```
:cexpr system('grep -n needle ' .. expand('##'))
```

That's a lot to type, though, so you might want to turn that into a proper command or mapping.

Welcome to [this particular rabbit hole](https://gist.github.com/romainl/56f0c28ef953ffc157f36cc495947ab3).

Comment: I have noticed `:vimgrep` is a lot nicer, but it's also painfully slow by comparison to running `:grep`. It's interesting you would mention the silence of things; what I've observed is that if the file list (`##`) is small enough, the command isn't shown, but once it crosses some threshold, it is. ‍♂️